# Slider label not updating with javascript value change

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I am building a tool that uses sliders for inputting values, which are then used in a calculation. I recently implemented a feature that allows users to save the model they created, which they access using a URL with the model parameters defined. The URL feature works perfectly, the values are updating, and even the slider portion of the sliders are updating based on the new values. But something weird is happening with the label that tells the user what the value is.

[image: The Problem]

The picture above shows the problem, where "Poverty Weight" has had its value changed to 90%, so the bar works, and the formula is updating fine, but the label next to the bar isn't changing. It changes if I make a change to the slider, and from that point forward it works fine, but the initial value is always the value set in the html, no matter what I do. (Changing povertyWeightLabel doesn't affect anything.)

I think that all of the relevant code is below, I included the CSS because I wonder if there is something funky happening with how the value is being accessed and saved before the javascript is running.

HTML:

```
<label>Poverty Weight:</label><br>
<div class="range-slider">
    <input class="range-slider__range" type="range" id="povertyWeight" value="30" min="0"
    max="100">
     <span class="range-slider__value" id="povertyWeightLabel">0</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```html
.range-slider {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0.3em;
}
.range-slider__range {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: calc(60%);
  height: 0.7em;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #d7dcdf;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.range-slider__range::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  appearance: none;
  width: 1.2em;
  height: 1.2em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #3a4a9f;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

.range-slider__range::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 1.2em;
  height: 1.2em;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #3a4a9f;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

.range-slider__value {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 4.5em;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1.1em;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #3a4a9f;
  padding: 0.2em 1em;
  margin-left: 8px;
}
.range-slider__value:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.25em;
  left: -7px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 7px solid transparent;
  border-right: 7px solid #3a4a9f;
  border-bottom: 7px solid transparent;
  content: "";
}
```

Javascript:

```
var rangeSlider = function () {
let slider = $(".range-slider");
let range = $(".range-slider__range");
let value = $(".range-slider__value");

slider.each(function () {
  value.each(function () {
    var value = $(this).prev().attr("value");
    $(this).html(value + "%");
  });

  range.on("input", function () {
    $(this)
      .next(value)
      .html(this.value + "%");
  });
});


   $("#povertyWeight").val(PW);
   rangeSlider();
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you?

```js
function rangeSlider() {
  var slider = $(".range-slider");
  let range = $(".range-slider__range");
  let value = $(".range-slider__value");

  slider.each(function() {
    value.each(function() {
      var value = $(this).prev().attr("value");
      $(this).html(value + "%");
    });

    range.on("input", function() {
      $(this)
        .next(value)
        .html(this.value + "%");
    });
  });

}
 rangeSlider();
```

```css
.range-slider {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0.3em;
}
.range-slider__range {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: calc(60%);
  height: 0.7em;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #d7dcdf;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.range-slider__range::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  appearance: none;
  width: 1.2em;
  height: 1.2em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #3a4a9f;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

.range-slider__range::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 1.2em;
  height: 1.2em;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #3a4a9f;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

.range-slider__value {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 4.5em;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1.1em;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #3a4a9f;
  padding: 0.2em 1em;
  margin-left: 8px;
}
.range-slider__value:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.25em;
  left: -7px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 7px solid transparent;
  border-right: 7px solid #3a4a9f;
  border-bottom: 7px solid transparent;
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Poverty Weight:</label><br>
<div class="range-slider">
    <input class="range-slider__range" type="range" id="povertyWeight" value="30" min="0"
    max="100">
     <span class="range-slider__value" id="povertyWeightLabel">0</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see what the major difference is? I see that you changed the way that the function is defined (using "function rangeslider() =" instead of "var rangeslider = function ()" and you added the code for calling the jquery library, am I missing something else?